# Showing Yes/No instead of checkbox in the View of ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to ASP.Net / MVC . I have created a View that I am populating from a model.
I am creating a rows for each item in the model to show their properties/attributes of model item.

One of the member is a bool , name is Staged. In the View I want to display it as Yes if true or No if false. The user will only be able to read it, so simple text Yes/No shall be sufficient.

I am using the following code in the cshtml

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Staged)         
   </td>
```

This however shows a checkbox in the place, how can I show it as Yes/No ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a custom html helper extension method like this:

```
@Html.YesNo(item.Staged)
```

Here is the code for this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString YesNo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool yesNo)
{
    var text = yesNo ? "Yes" : "No";
    return new MvcHtmlString(text);
}
```

This way you could re-use it throughout the site with a single line of Razor code.

Comment: Will this method be written in the view file ?

Comment: No, create a new static class within your project. I usually put them in an Extensions folder.

Comment: Getting an error no method definition= I created an extensions folder and added a static class MyExtensions and the static method quoted above in that.. updated in the relevent line in view with the one @Html.YesNo(item.Staged) , I guess I need to do something else as well..

Comment: Give me 5 mins, will check for you.

Comment: namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
 public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
 {

  public static MvcHtmlString YesNo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool yesNo)
  {
   var text = yesNo ? "Yes" : "No";
   return new MvcHtmlString(text);
  }
 }
}

Comment: The above code should def work, I've tested it. What is the error if it doesn't work?

Comment: I have used this code -> namespace MvcApplication5.Extensions
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString YesNo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool yesNo)
        {
            var text = yesNo ? "Yes" : "No";
            return new MvcHtmlString(text);
        }
    }
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42144/discussion-between-ahmed-and-hutchonoid)

Comment: You need to change the namespace to this  System.Web.Mvc instead of MvcApplication5.Extensions . Please accept when it works for you. :)

Comment: To call the helper class in your view you need to call it, for example at the top of your view you will add `@using 'YourNamespace.ClassName`

Answer (score 7):

use Html.Raw and render the string conditionally based on model value true/false

```
 <td>
      @Html.Raw((Model.Staged)?"Yes":"No")     
 </td>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Staged)
```

to

```
    @(item.Staged?"Yes":"No")
```

This is the simplest way to achieve what your requirements.

Comment: In newer version of MVC 5 I used @(Model.myField?"Yes":"No"). The only change being "item" to "Model". And my field name.

Comment: If you are using @ model SomeNamespace.SomeModel then item will become Model, but in case @ model IEnumerable<somenamespace.somemodel>  item will become the name of variable in the foreach loop. it is applicable on mvc 3+

Answer (score 3):

In the model, you would need to make a new property that does something like this...

```
public string ItemStagedYesNo = (item.Staged) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

then in the view, do

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ItemStagedYesNo);
```