# MVC model boolean display yes or no

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a boolean field in my model in mvc 4 entity framework 4.5

i want to display the field in my view

i use this call

```
@item.isTrue
```

but i got true or false,

#### i want to get yes when true and no when false

what should i do please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270754/showing-yes-no-instead-of-checkbox-in-the-view-of-asp-net-mvc/20270845#20270845

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In your view:

```
@(item.isTrue?"Yes":"No")
```

Answer (score 28):

You could use a custom html helper extension method like this:

```
@Html.YesNo(item.IsTrue)
```

Here is the code for this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString YesNo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool yesNo)
{
    var text = yesNo ? "Yes" : "No";
    return new MvcHtmlString(text);
}
```

This way you could re-use it throughout the site with a single line of Razor code.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on DigitalD's answer, you could consider wrapping this up in an extension method:

```
public static string ToFriendlyString(this Boolean b)
{
    return b ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

Then you can use it all over the place:

```
@item.IsTrue.ToFriendlyString()
```

Answer (score 5):

In your model write something like this:

```
public Nullable<bool> Active
{
    get;
    set;
}
public string ISActive
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)this.Active ? "Yes" : "NO";
    }
}
```

**Active** is a boolean property, we create **ISActive** property for reading its value and show appropriate message to user.

Comment: Something like this is my preferred technique.

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution similar to @Lucas Niewohner's, taken from [Scott on Writing .NET](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/11/22/using-templates-to-display-boolean-values-as-yes-no-options.aspx).

Create a DisplayTemplate called `YesNo.cshtml`:

```
@model bool
@if (Model)
{
    @Html.Raw("Yes")
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw("No")
}
```

Then decorate the ViewModel with `UIHint` to wire it up:

```
public class foo
{
...
[UIHint="YesNo"]
public bool SomeBooleanValue { get; set; }
...
}
```

Now you can use your MVC helpers as usual:

```
...
@Html.DisplayFor (x=> x.SomeBooleanValue)
...
```

You can take it one step further to create an EditorTemplate `YesNo.cshtml` as well:

```
@model bool
@Html.DropDownList("", new SelectListItem[] { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = Model }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = !Model }})
```

This approach is particularly helpful if you want to use the ViewModel in several places with a consistent implementation since you only have to associate the template in one place.

Comment: UIHint syntax should be [UIHint("YesNo")]

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but...

One useful method missed by other answers answers is the Custom DisplayTemplate method.
By putting this Code:

```
@model bool
<p>@{Model ? "Yes" : "No"}</p>
```

Into a Partial View (Maybe `YesNo.cshtml`) in the Display Templates folder (`/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`).  Then, in your view, use this line:

```
@Html.Display(item.isTrue,"YesNo")
```

where "YesNo" is whatever you named your Partial View, *minus the .cshtml extension*.

By adding the second string (the `templateName`), you tell DisplayExtensions to display the boolean with your custom template, rather than the default method (a checkbox).

This method may not be the simplest for this situation, but it comes in handy with more complex situations (such as, say, a custom calendar for selecting dates)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a descriptor prop for your reason:

```
public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

public string IsActiveDescriptor => IsActive.HasValue && IsActive ? "Yes" : "NO";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a rush, or you use an integer instead of bit. (I do this in case you have a  third option later and your `yes/no` becomes `yes, no, octopus`,as mine always seem to do, here is the simple plain quick dirty way of going... 
declare your variable at the top of the Razor view:

```
@model MyModel
@using My.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "";
    string Active = ""; //This will hold your "Yes" or "No"
 }
```

As you go through your items...The following code will set your string variable `Active` to "Yes" or "No" and then you simply display it as is on the page (with no `@Html.DisplayFor(...)` markup.

```
@{if (item.Active == 0){Active = "No";}else{Active = "Yes";}}
@Active
```

In case you don't know already, surrounding the entire "if" Statement with `@{}` makes life easy - no `@`'s are needed within the brackets...